# useRef() causes TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'undefined'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-effect, use-ref

I am trying to use useEffect and useRef() to get the latest value of my counter as well as compare to the previous value so that I know if I need to call the addValues or removeValues function.

I followed the directions [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/accessing-previous-props-state-react-hooks/) I'm working with Typescript and when I set `prevSubjectAddressCounterRef.current = subjectAddressCounter;` I get the error `TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.`

How can I fix this error and ensure that when I update the count on the state that I am working with the latest value?

Please see the relevant code below.

```
const FormGroup = prop => {
  const [subjectAddressCounter, setSubjectAddressCounter] = useState(0); // changing to 0 || undefined causes this not to function correctly because you can't add to undefined


  const prevSubjectAddressCounterRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    prevSubjectAddressCounterRef.current = subjectAddressCounter; // this causes Typescript error above

    if (prevSubjectAddressCounterRef.current < subjectAddressCounter) {
      // call function to addValues
      addValues();
    }

    if (prevSubjectAddressCounterRef.current === subjectAddressCounter) {
      // call function to removeValues
      removeValues();
    }


  }, [subjectAddressCounter]);


  const addSection = section => {
    if (section.section === SectionTitle.subjectAddress) {
      setSubjectAddressCounter(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
    }
  };

  const removeSection = section => {
    if (section.section === SectionTitle.subjectAddress) {
      setSubjectAddressCounter(prevCount => prevCount - 1);
    }
  };

return (
   ... 
   button onClick={() => addSection(form)}

   button onClick={() => removeSection(form)}

 )

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to pass the initial value and define the type of the const because `undefined` is not equal to `number`, that's why is throwing the error `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'undefined'`. I think it should look like this:

```
const prevSubjectAddressCounterRef = useRef<number>(0);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this doesn't fix my primary issue. Please see the update above.